# cakephp 3.x data not saving when Saving data into 2 tables with belongs to relation

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0, belongs-to

I have two tables `users` and `user_details`, `user_details` has field `user_id` relation between them us `user hasOne user_detail` and `user_detail belongs to user`, i have following code in my view file

```
echo $this->Form->create($user);
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('user_detail.first_name');
echo $this->Form->input('user_detail.last_name');
echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'))
echo $this->Form->end()
```

my `UsersController` code is

```
public function add() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
            'associated' => ['UserDetails']
        ]);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

if i print_r($user) after patch entry  than i get the follwing array

```
App\Model\Entity\User Object
(
    [name] => User1
    [email] => user1@user2.com
    [user_detail] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => user1
            [last_name] => last naem
        )

        [[new]] => 1
        [[accessible]] => Array
        (
            [*] => 1
        )

        [[dirty]] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1
            [email] => 1
            [user_detail] => 1
        )

        [[original]] => Array
        (
        )

        [[virtual]] => Array
        (
        )

        [[errors]] => Array
        (
        )

        [[repository]] => Users
)
```

This is my User Model i have removed the validation rules

```
    <?php
        namespace App\Model\Table;
        use App\Model\Entity\User;
        use Cake\ORM\Query;
        use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
        use Cake\ORM\Table;
        use Cake\Validation\Validator;

        /**
         * Users Model
         *
         * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\HasMany $UserDetails
         */
        class UsersTable extends Table
        {

            /**
            * Initialize method
            * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
            * @return void
            */
        public function initialize(array $config)
        {
            parent::initialize($config);

            $this->table('users');
            $this->displayField('id');
            $this->primaryKey('id');

            $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

            $this->hasMany('UserDetails', [
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
            ]);
        }


        }
    ?>
```

This is my User detail Model i have removed the validation rules

```
<?php
    namespace App\Model\Table;
    use App\Model\Entity\UserDetail;
    use Cake\ORM\Query;
    use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
    use Cake\ORM\Table;
    use Cake\Validation\Validator;

    /**
     * UserDetails Model
     *
     * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Users
     */
    class UserDetailsTable extends Table
    {

    /**
     * Initialize method
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('user_details');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }


    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

But data saving only in `user` table not in `user_detail` table don't know what is the problem.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any obvious error. I would suggest that you do some debugging, and update your question with the results. Start with checking what exactly `$this->request->data` contains, and what `$user` looks like after patching it (ie the values that it holds, the dirty state of the properties, etc).

Comment: This is My array option 
App\Model\Entity\User Object
(
    [name] => User1
    [email] => user1@user2.com
    [user_detail] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => user1
            [last_name] => user1 last
        )
    [[new]] => 1
    [[accessible]] => Array(
            [*] => 1
 )
    [[dirty]] => Array (
            [name] => 1
            [email] => 1
            [user_detail] => 1
        )
    [[original]] => Array ( )
    [[virtual]] => Array ()
    [[errors]] => Array()
    [[repository]] => Users
)

Comment: Please put the code in your question where it can be formatted properly, code in comments is highly unreadable, and not helpful for future readers.

Comment: i edit the question if you need i can attache the model code also

Comment: The fact that `user_detail` is an array instead of an entity, indicates that there is possibly something wrong with your association config, so yes, please show that part of your model/table code.

Comment: added model code also user model and user detial model both

Comment: `hasMany != hasOne`... I'm not going to add that as an answer, if that is the problem, then I'd vote to close the question instead, as the problem is merely more than a typo.

Comment: please explain i did not understand i create model using cake bake command please tell me what is the problem there

Comment: Look at the `UserDetails` association configuration, you are using a `hasMany` association, not a `hasOne` one.

Comment: Thanks its solve my problem